# Server sends TCP packets without receiving ACK from client

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I have an iOS chat app talking to a java XMPP chat server via TCP socket. The server machine(machine 1) was running redhat linux. Recently I moved the chat server to another Linux machine(machine 2) with similar configuration except that it had more processors. The way the server works is that once it receives a particular data from client(data1) then it sends 2 xml packets to the client(data2 and data3). Looking at the packets in wireshark, I see the below
the consistent behavior in machine1.

```
iOS App          Java server
  SYN      -->
           <--   SYN,ACK
  ACK      -->
TCP handshake ends here 

  data1     -->   
          <--    ACK

          <--    data2
  ACK      -->
          <--    data3
  ACK      -->
```

But in machine2 it works like below.(not always but most of the time)

```
iOS App          Java server
  SYN      -->
           <--   SYN,ACK
  ACK      -->
TCP handshake ends here

  data1     -->   
          <--    ACK

          <--    data2
          <--    data3
  ACK      -->
  ACK      -->
```

As seen above the ACK for 2 packets are sent all at once by the client. 
Why is there such a change in behavior. Since the app is the same in both the cases what could have made the server send data 3 without receiving ACK for data2. I have verified most of the TCP socket related properties in these machines like send buffer , TCO_NODELAY etc. but all these looks the same. What can I do if the need the behavior as it was in the machine1.

I ve also noticed that this behavior is mainly seen when I connect through wifi.

Comment: By design and it's not always deterministic either. Do an internet search for TCP Window Size.  The window size that an endpoint uses varies greatly depending on operating system, network adapter type, and other factors including how the application sends data.

Comment: Why do you think you need the behavour as at machine 1? You can't observe that from an application in any way. There are various algorithms in use for delayed and coalesced ACKs, and machine 2 might be *benefiting* from them.

Comment: When my client reads the data from TCP, in machine 1 it was able to read data 2 and provide it to the packet handler method and then when it reads data3 send it over to the packet handler method again. But when using machine 2, the client is reading data 2 and data 3 together and calling the message handler method with the data2+data3. My crappy client code does nt want that :). I should change the client but was looking if I could do something at server side as a temporary fix.

Comment: Fix your 'crappy' code. TCP is a byte stream, not a message service, and the location of ACKs in the stream doesn't change that.